# Wordpress - Dont show Post with certain Category in Admin

Tags: php, wordpress

i need some hints/tipps/advices for the following.

1) In Admin Panel, if i click on Post, i dont wanne see Post with a certain category. We call this categroy "userevents".

2) Now i need a new menu link in the sidebar. If i click on it, i get the same view like if i click on Post. But here i just wanne see the Post with the Category "userevents".

Is this possible, and if yes, how can i do it^^

I already found Administration Menus for adding a new menuelink.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus

```
add_options_page( 'My Plugin Options', 'My Plugin', 'manage_options', 'my-unique-identifier', 'my_plugin_options' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to hook into `pre_get_posts`, check if `is_admin` and main query. Then get current screen with `get_current_screen`, check if it's post editing one and then [alter query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts#Examples) to exclude posts from your category

```
function alter_query($query)
{
    if ($query->is_main_query() && is_admin())
    {
        $screen=get_current_screen();
        if (isset($screen['id']) && $screen['id'] == 'edit-post')
        {
            //do stuff here
        }
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'alter_query');
```